# Is there a Cuba equivalent of the Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, rails-console, pry, cuba

I'd like to be able to test classes that I require in Cuba without having to require them each individually using the irb. What I've been using instead is an endpoint that runs `binding.pry`, but I'd much rather be able to use something like the Rails Console.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the question, but could you simply create a file that requires the dependencies you'd like to test, and then require that in IRB (a sort of "helper" only for the IRB context)?

Answer (score 0):

You can `$ pry -r ./app` where `app.rb` requires all of your project's files.

To require all files, you can look at something like

```
Dir["./models/**/*.rb"].each { |rb| require rb }
```